# Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android

I'm try save a paint with image type. Then convert image to bitmap to save SQLite database. I has get the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" at line "Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paint, 100, paint.length);". How can I do fix ?

CanvasActivity.java

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = relativeLayout.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArray);
            byte[] paint = byteArray.toByteArray();

            MainActivity.database.Insert_Item(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), paint);
            Toast.makeText(CanvasActivity.this, "Added a paint.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(CanvasActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

PaintAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // Initialize view and mapping
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

        viewHolder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set items
    PaintItem paintItem = itemList.get(position);

    viewHolder.textViewName.setText(paintItem.getName());
    // Convert byte[] -> bitmap
    byte[] paint = paintItem.getPaint();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paint, 100, paint.length);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return convertView;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This type of error generally occurs if we try to get an item at index from the data list which is actually greater than the size we return in getCount() inside Adapter class. Can you paste your complete PaintAdapter class.

Comment: Sorry, I can not add more code to my article. Above are 2 image for my code.

Comment: Code seems fine. I doubt may paint could be null on this line paintItem.getPaint(); so, could you debug it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that may be cause by 1. paint is null 
2. paint is less than 100 bytes thus getting this error when the offset wants to start at the 100 position.
are you sure your paint file is provided to decodeByteArray complete?

Comment: Probably so. May can the data added is null. I tried reduce offset is 0 - 95.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you save image to database by this way: image to base64 code, 
the base64 utils is under android.util